# Run bash scripts from Perl threads

Tags: multithreading, bash, perl

My script should have n subroutines (**my_proc**) to run simultaneously, each of them runs bash script and one sub (**check_procs**) checks if subs has finished.

```
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %proc_status :shared;
my %thr;

foreach my $i (1,2,3,4) {
    $proc_status{$i}=0;
}

sub my_proc {
    my $arg=shift(@_);
    while (1) {
         sleep(2);
         print "Proc $arg Started\n";
         #exec("/bin/bash","sleep_for_10_sec.bash") or die("Can't exec");   # case 1
         #`sleep_for_10_sec.bash &`;                                        # case 2      

         print "Proc $arg Finished\n";
         {
         lock(%proc_status);
         $proc_status{$arg}=1;
         }
    }
}

sub check_procs {
    my $all_finished;
    while (! $all_finished) {
            sleep 5;
            print "CHECK: \n";
            $all_finished=1;
            foreach my $num (1,2,3,4) {
                    if ($proc_status{$num} == 1) {
                            print "CHECK: procedure $num has finished\n";
                    } else {
                        $all_finished=0;
                    }
            }
    }
    print "All jobs finished\n";
}

foreach my $num (1,2,3,4) {
    $thr{"$num"} = new threads \&my_proc,$num;
}

my $thr_check= new threads \&check_procs;
$thr_check->join();
```

And here are the sleep_for_10_sec.bash

```
ls
# bunch of other stuff 
sleep 10
echo "finished sleep"
```

I don't want **my_proc** subs to wait "sleep_for_10_sec.bash" command to be executed, after browsing I have found that either **#case1** or **#case2** should work, but they both fail.

the output of #case1:

```
 Proc 1 Started
 [ls result]
 finsihed sleep
```

the output of #case2:

```
Proc 1 Started
Proc 2 Started
Proc 3 Started
Proc 4 Started
CHECK:
CHECK:
Proc 4 Finished
Proc 2 Finished
Proc 3 Finished
Proc 1 Finished
Proc 3 Started
Proc 1 Started
Proc 2 Started
Proc 4 Started
CHECK:
CHECK: procedure 1 has finished
CHECK: procedure 2 has finished
CHECK: procedure 3 has finished
CHECK: procedure 4 has finished
```

But I expect something like this :

```
 Proc 1 Started
 Proc 2 Started
 Proc 3 Started
 Proc 4 Started
 Proc 1 Finished
 Proc 1 Started
 Proc 3 Finished
 Proc 3 Started
 Proc 4 Finished
 Proc 4 Started
 Proc 2 Finished
 Proc 2 Started
 CHECK:
 CHECK:
 CHECK:
 CHECK: procedure 1 has finished
 CHECK: procedure 2 has finished
 CHECK: procedure 3 has finished
 CHECK: procedure 4 has finished
```

Actually I get wanted result in case of redirecting output to " > log", but anyway after:

```
 Proc 1 Started
 Proc 2 Started
 Proc 3 Started
 Proc 4 Started
```

it waits "sleep_for_10_sec.bash" to finish.

This is my first project where I use "thread" and "exec", could someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` shouldn't be combined with threads. `exec` launches a new program within the current process, so when you call `exec` from one thread, the program the threads were executing disappears. Since the threads would have no program to execute, `exec` kills the threads as well.

It's not clear to me why case 2 doesn't work (edit: see ikegami's comment below). I would think it would launch the process, run it in the background, and allow the Perl thread to immediately continue. It doesn't seem to do that, but this code will:

```
system("/bin/bash sleep_for_10_sec.bash &");        # case 3
```

Comment: Backticks wait for the child's STDOUT to be closed, so it only returns after the background program exits (unless you redirect the background program's STDOUT).

Comment: Running `sh -c '/bin/bash sleep_for_10_sec.bash &'` (as a `system()` invocation does) seems silly -- why launch two shells vs one?

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Because you said it's a `bash` script.

Comment: @ikegami, I'm not the OP. That said -- Perl doesn't provide a way to directly invoke the interpreter you want? (In Python, for instance, I can directly `subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'sleep_for_10_sc.bash'])`, and as long as I don't pass `shell=True` there's no implicit `sh -c`).

Comment: @Charles Duffy, That python code is not equivalent. You forgot to account for the `&`. Now, mob could have written `system("/bin/bash -c 'sleep_for_10_sec.bash &'");` in which case the shell could have been avoid uses `system('bash', 'c', 'sleep_for_10_sec.bash &')` This still creates two shells, though, both of them `bash`.

Comment: @ikegami, given as creating a `Popen` object doesn't `wait()` for the invoked command to exit (and thus runs it in the background, just as the OP here wishes to), other than the obvious typo, I don't very well see how it isn't.

Comment: That is the difference. `system` does `wait`

Comment: Right, but `system()` with a `&` in the text creates a subprocess for the thing we actually *want* to run, making the effective behavior equivalent to something that *doesn't* wait.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Your Python code is NOT equivalent to code that doesn't have to wait, because it does have to wait.

Comment: "It does have to wait" -- could you explain the basis for that claim?

Comment: Sure, *if* the interpreter doesn't have a reasonable SIGCHILD handler.

Comment: Ug, adding a signal handler just compounds the problem! Now, you don't need to just wait, you have to worry about interrupted operations too!

Comment: That waits *in a non-blocking mode*. (I misread you as referring to the blocking version of the call above; now this thread makes more sense).

Comment: @mob, #case 3 worked perfectly, thanks, and also thank you for detailed explanation I will never combine those two again.

Answer (score 1):

> *`exec("/bin/bash","sleep_for_10_sec.bash") or die("Can't exec");   # case 1`*

`exec` replaces the program running in the current process with another program. At the same time, the existing threads are terminated (since the program they want to execute is no longer there), replaced with a single thread executing the new program.

This means that `exec` never returns (except on error). Threads or no threads, `exec` is not what you want, because you don't want your program to stop running.

---

> *But I expect something like this:*

Are you sure you want to launch `sleep_for_10_sec.bash` 4 times every two seconds (meaning you can have up to 20 of them running at a time) as your desired output indicates?

Are you sure you don't care if `sleep_for_10_sec.bash` completes or not as your desired output indicates?

If so, why are you using threads at all? You could simply use the following:

```
sub start {
   my $num = shift;
   say "Proc $num Started";
   system('bash -c sleep_for_10_sec.bash &');
   say "Proc $num Finished";
}

for my $pass (1..2) {
   start($_) for 1..4;
   sleep 2;
   start($_) for 1..4;
   sleep 2;
   start($_) for 1..4;
   sleep 1;
   if ($pass == 1) {
      say "CHECK:";
   } else {
      say "CHECK: procedure $_ has finished" for 1..4;
   }
}
```

---

I think you want

```
use threads;

use Thread::Queue qw( );  # 3.01+

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 4;

sub worker {
    my $num = shift;
    say "Job $num Started\n";
    system("sleep_for_10_sec.bash");  # Make sure starts with #! and is executable.
    say "Job $num Finished\n";
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      while (defined( my $job = $q->dequeue() )) {
         worker($job);
      }
   }    

   $q->enqueue(1..4, 1..4);

   $q->end();
   $_->join() for threads->list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation. I finally get how exec works( I hope :)). #case 3 suggested by @mob works perfectly. Anyway your answer was very informative, I appreciate it very much, thanks again.

Comment: That's an awful choice!!!!! If you're ok with case #3, then you should use the first snippet I posted instead. It's only half the lines (23 instead of 50), and it completely avoids the complexity of using threads (which are completely useless to you).